# Allow just one click in class JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a link that will load via ajax some content.

My problem is, I don't want to remove the text "Load comments", I just want to not allow more clicks in this class.

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="showcomments" id="'.$idf.'">Load comments</a>
```

Jquery

```
var Progressajax = false;
$(function() {
     $(".showcomments").click(function(){
    
               if(Progressajax) return;
                   Progressajax = true;
    
    var element = $(this);
    var id = element.attr("id");
       
    Progressajax = false;
           alert("ok");
           $(data).hide().prependTo('.varload'+id).fadeIn(1000);
         //$(element).remove();
        $(element).removeAttr("href");
        $(element).removeClass('showcomments');
    }); 
    });
```

I just want to see OK the first time. How can I remove this class?

```
$(element).removeClass('showcomments');
```

This is not working...

http://jsfiddle.net/qsn1tuk1/

Comment: `$('.showcomments')` will find all elements that have that class, and attach click handler to them. if you later remove the class, that doesn't do ANYTHING to the click handler.  you'd have to remove the click handler itself, or have the handler check if the element still has the appropriate classs

Comment: It sounds like you want to use `$.off()` which will turn off the listener on a class. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/off/) is the doc on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use jQuery's `one()` function

```
$(".showcomments").one("click", function() {
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_one.asp

> The one() method attaches one or more event handlers for the selected elements, and specifies a function to run when the event occurs.
>
> When using the one() method, the event handler function is only run ONCE for each element.

Answer (score 1):

When you bind an event handler, you bind to the *element*, not to the *class*. Removing a class from an element doesn't change which event handlers are bound to the element.

You could use [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove the event handler:

`$(this).off('click');`

http://jsfiddle.net/om6ggvyu/