# mbox - firing 3 times instead of once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code snippet I'm using to define some tracking on my site - however it appears to be firing the "QuickViewAddToCartClicked" 3 times in stead of once.

I've spent an hour logically trying to think through what is causing this.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Please see my code below:

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( ".quickview_btn" ).click(function() {
           var quickview_url = $(this).attr("href");
           var qvURL = $(this).attr("href");
           $(".quickview_btn").colorbox({ 
               href: qvURL, 
              opacity: 0.6,
              onComplete: function(){
                  $( ".qlBtns" ).click(function() {
                      mboxDefine('dynamicElement5', 'QuickViewAddToCartClicked');
                      mboxUpdate( 'QuickViewAddToCartClicked', 'Clicked=Yess');
                  });
              }
           });
           mboxDefine('dynamicElement', 'QuickViewPLPclicked');
           mboxUpdate( 'QuickViewPLPclicked', 'paramURL='+quickview_url);
      });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow just one click in class JQUERY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616022/allow-just-one-click-in-class-jquery)

Comment: I tried using the suggested edit with .one("click", function() {...}
This did not work for me - and i dont seem to have multiple .qlBtns classes.

Comment: You need a little bit of refactoring in your code...for example, this `$(".quickview_btn").colorbox` should be `$(this).colorbox`..also instead of `$( ".qlBtns" )` maybe you need to find just the closest one to the `$( ".quickview_btn" )` clicked!

Comment: If you add the relevant bits of your html or even create a jsfiddle then helping you will be much easier.