# jquery function include only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building single page application with jquery. so assume I have a sidebar like this

```
dashboard.html
order.html
```

and each time i click on it I load the content via ajax. It work fine but I go back and forth btw pages I notice the script got loaded twice or more. How to solve this?

Comment: You should just load the HTML content with AJAX, load scripts only in the main page.

Comment: @Barmar No, it will have conflict if my app is big, and it's a waste of you load everything at once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow just one click in class JQUERY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616022/allow-just-one-click-in-class-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Put the scripts and HTML in separate files. Then keep track of whether you've already loaded a script, and don't load it again.

```
var dashboard_js_loaded = false;
$("#dashboard").click(function() {
    $("#content").load("dashboard.html", function() {
        if (!dashboard_js_loaded) {
            $.getScript("dashboard.js", function() {
                dashboard_js_loaded = true;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Maybe a library like `require.js` can be used to manage this more generally. Or you can just write a simple function that keeps track of which JS files have been loaded in an object.

Comment: is require.js a must in building SPA without framework?

Comment: @AliciaBrandon I've never used it myself, so I guess not. But I haven't written any SPA that needs different JS for each component.

Comment: without require.js, and I put my js within my htmls, is that a bad practice? a waste of memory right? suppose I have 5 tabs, the in-memory function or variable are cache even though i clicked on other tab correct?

Comment: If you reload the file, it will redefine the functions, and the previous definitions will be cleaned up by the garbage collector.

Comment: I gave you a suggestion how to do it in my answer. Why are you asking me questions about other solutions?